# How to Pass Values between two different components on click of button in Angular 4(without updating the route URL)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-forms

I am new to Angular 4 and got stuck while passing data from one component to another while clicking on a button without using AcitvatedRoute(without passing the data in the URL)

My searchOption.component.html holds the below code for Submit button:

```
<td><a routerLink="searchDetails"> <button id="testButton"  (click)="sendVal()">Submit</button></a></td>
```

And my searchOption.component.ts stores the below code:

```
sendVal() {
  this.selectedAcc = this.signUpForm.form.value.accNo;
  console.log("Account Lists3::"+this.selectedAcc);
  this.router.navigate(['./searchDetails', this.selectedAcc])
}
```

My requirement is to pass the this.selectedAcc to another component searchDetails.component.ts on click of the button.

Comment: Do you mix up routing and component interaction? 
Maybe you should first have a look on the different [possibilties of component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)
@PraveenM is only showing one possiblity in his post.

Answer (score -1):

I have answered a similar question like this before, I believe you'll find the answer here. [Angular 2 send array another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247776/angular-2-send-array-another-page/46248250#46248250)

Here is useful secion of the answer.

```js
export class WeatherService {

  weatherClass: Weather;
  
  //BehaviorSubject can store the last value given until the service destroyed or otherwise changed
  private data: BehaviorSubject<Weather> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  otherWeather(city: string) {
    return this.http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=0f3fb9fa31ad3d41f1bb2bd0841c3f2f&q=${city}&units=imperial&cnt=10`).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
  
  setData(value: Weather) {
    this.data.next(value);
  }
  
  getData(): Observable<Weather> {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ParentComponet implements OnInit {

  parentData: Type = ["ADANA", "ADIYAMAN", "AFYONKARAHİSAR", "AĞRI", "AMASYA", "ANKARA", "ANTALYA", "ARTVİN"];;

  constructor(private service: WeatherService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.service.otherWeather(this.value.text).subscribe( (data: Weather) => { 
    this.service.setData(data);
    });
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponet implements OnInit {

  childData: Weather;

  constructor(private service: WeatherService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData.subscribe((vales: Weather) => {
      this.childData = vales;
    });
  }

}
```

With this approach, you'll notice that the data is not returned straightaway and the code would not wait for data. You'll have to do any TypeScript logic related to data within the `subscribe()` block for it to work. HTML will update itself when the value changes. Using this method when the value of BehaviorSubject changes, anywhere that is subscribed to `getData()` method will also receive new data.

Comment: @PaulRoub  and sdfx Thanks for the advice guys, I have extracted the useful part of that answer and added to this answer.