# Shared Service between two sibling components in Angular4

Tags: angular, service, components, shared

I have two sibling components, one MapComponent and one MenuComponent. Every project is displayed on a GoogleMap (MapComponent), when I click on a marker it gets the id for that project (siteId). What I want to do is to get that project id and use it in the links of my menu, so that for every project it makes a unique link with the project id, like: /project/10001
I have a shared service since sibling components can't exchange values directly. I can write the project id to the shared service but my problem is with picking up the project id in my menulinks. How do I do this? (I'm using Angular4)

MapComponent

```
clickedMarker(siteId: string) {
    this.ss.selectedSite(siteId);
    this.route.navigate(['project', siteId]);
  }
```

MenuComponent

```
selectedSite = this.sharedService.siteId;

<a class="submenu" *ngFor="let submenu of item.submenu, let i = index"
     md-list-item [routerLink]="[submenu.url, selectedSite]">
  <i class="material-icons spacer">{{submenu.icon}}</i>
  <div *ngIf="!minimalMenuOpen">{{submenu.name}}</div>
</a>
```

SharedService

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  public constructor() {
    console.log('Service is succesfully initialized');
  }

  siteId;
  selectedSite(siteId) {
    this.siteId = siteId;
    console.log(siteId);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do in your situation. [Angular 2 send array another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247776/angular-2-send-array-another-page/46248250#46248250)

I recommend the service approach as you have most of your components setup towards that

```js
activePage: number;

constructor(private path: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.path.queryParams.subscribe(path => {
      // If there is a value
      this.activePage = +path["id"];
      if (isUndefined(this.activePage)) {
        // What if there is no value
      }
    });
```

Can you not generate the links like this?

```js
> MenuComponent TS file

selectedSite;
this.sharedService.getSelectedSiteId().subscribe(
  (siteId: any) => {
    this.selectedSite = siteId;
  });
```

```html
> MenuComponent HTML file

<!-- This make sure links don't start creating till selectedSite available -->
<ng-container *ngIf="!selectedSite">
  <a class="submenu" *ngFor="let submenu of item.submenu, let i = index" md-list-item [routerLink]="[submenu.url]" [queryParams]="{id:'"+ selectedSite + "'}">
    <i class="material-icons spacer">{{submenu.icon}}</i>
    <div *ngIf="!minimalMenuOpen">{{submenu.name}}</div>
  </a>
</ng-container>
```

Your service need bit of tweaking for this.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  public constructor() {
    console.log('Service is succesfully initialized');
  }

  private siteId: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  selectedSite(siteId) {
    this.siteId.next(siteId);
    console.log(siteId);
  }
  
  getSelectedSiteId(): Observable<any> {
    return this.siteId.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference between BehaviorSubject and Observable? Because I see both being used often by other people.

Comment: BehaviourSubject keeps the last value as long as the component stay alive or otherwise value changed. Observable is an asynchronously method, its used to manage asynchronous data. If the value changes on something that Observable looking at (I.E. variable) it send the change to the `.subscribe()` method to use that data. Thats why `Promise` runs only once, and `Observable` may run multiple times.

Comment: Ok this solution works, however the routerLink is already instantiated so I need to update the routerLink (which is not working now), any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can use `ActivatedRoute` in the `constructor` of the destination component to filter the `queryParams` on URL. I'll add a sample snippet above

Comment: Thank you for adding the example, but it is still not working. I do load a menu with links to pages, those pages need to get the selected Id from a map component. So after I click on a marker on the map, the links inside the menu component need to be updated. This is not the case now, so I get undefined. How do I solve this?

Comment: @viddrawings Apologies for late response, I've updated the post. See if this   get any close solving the problem

Comment: You sir, are a genius! This completely solved it for me! Thank you so much for your patience and time.